# Is there a faster way to add my Many-to-Many DBIC relationships?

Tags: sql, perl, orm, dbi, dbix-class

I have a Many to Many relationship Between what are called

Objects and ObjectGroups.

An ObjectGroup is just a 'Group' or Objects and an Object can belong to many Object Groups.

For example

```
ObjectGroupA
-------------
ObjectA
ObjectB
ObjectC

ObjectGroupB   
-------------
ObjectA
ObjectB
ObjectC
ObjectD
```

These ObjectGroups belong to a device

I have put the Objects and ObjectGroups into the Database via multicreate but now I need to build up the Many-to-Many relationships ( I wasn't able to work out how to do this
via multicreate. I did read the documentation). like below;

```
my $device = $device_rs->create(
 {
   devicename      => $deviceName,
   objects         => \@objects,
   object_groups   => \@objectgroups
 }
);
```

Then for the relationships I build up a hash of arrays where the ObjectGroup(Parent) is the key and the array contains the Names of the objects. Then for each object group I 
move through the list of child objects and add them via add_to_$rel.

```
foreach my $parent (keys %childobjects) { 
  my $parent_objectgroup = $device->object_groups->find({objectgroupname => $parent}); 
    foreach my $child (@{$childobjects{$parent}}) { 
      my $child_object   = $device->objects->find({objectname => $child}); 
        if ($child_object) { 
          #add the child object from the array to the object-group 
          $parent_objectgroup->add_to_childobjects($child_object); 
        } 
     } 
}
```

This works, but is VERY slow as I have a lot of relationships to build up. Can anybody suggest a faster way to do this with DBIC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so unless I am totally lost on this, there is one thing that seems to spring to mind.

You seem to be populating **bulk** data into these tables as some kind of initial load or conversion or something. And it would seem that from your last routine you already have some concept of which `devices` have which `objects` and which `group` and so on by the matching that you are doing.

With that in mind, it seems the logical thing to do is just populate each table with the *relational keys* you already know about. Loading up each table is going to be a lot faster than looping through and trying to work out the relations that you should already know in your data.

The operations you are trying to use to *bulk load* are intended for more *atomic* purposes where you are going to add new relations in a many to many context. These will work well programatically, as you add an additional `device` or `object group` etc.

But as you should already know the associations of this bulk data, just load it into the tables.

Comment: Thanks Neil.I agree with your approach however the issue is I don't have all of the data until the bulk load has completed because my primary keys are all Auto Increment ID's. So I still need to do the bulk load first, then retrieve the ID's.

Comment: What's the database? On MySQL auto-increment keys off the last insert. And anything using sequences you should be able to just adjust the pool. Clarifying my point, **include** the primary key id's in the data you load, since **that** is your relational information.

Comment: ok thank you, so basically I should be able to infer what the keys are without going to the database ( except for the first insert ). Then use them to add during my bulk insert. thanks I'll give that a go. I think there is a way to do this via DBIC and multicreate but I just can't work this out.